# Potentiometer current range in which it can operate

Tags: potentiometer

solar panels generate 8 amps current can this current be handled by using a potentiometer. especially this potentiometer which i am mentioning in the link https://www.tanotis.com/products/rotary-potentiometer-wirewound-abw1-series-5-kohm-linear-1-turns-w-panel-5k-ab-elektronik?gclid=CJCC6pn__9ICFdKKaAoduyUPgg&variant=19738052997.kindly reply at the earliest.

Comment: No. Or to be more precise, absolutely no way can the pot in the link be used.

Comment: What are you trying to do that makes you think you need to subject a potentiometer to the full current your panels can provide?

Comment: This has a strong smell of an xy problem.  You should explain what it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because all the links are dead and the question body doesn't contain enough information to answer it without further details.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use this pot as a variable resistor with your panels (2 wire).

You could only use it as a potentiometer only (3 wire), provided your panels are low voltage (~12V).

I would comment to ask you to clarify your intention but I don't have the rep.

Comment: But it has more work related to battery(maintenance of battery) less with the tracking and it is costly too. so the 2nd option was to use a rheostat to manually operate at MPPT but the problem here is, it is too large that cannot be fit to my box containing voltmeter and ammeter for various measurement so i thought can this work be taken care by potentiometer so that panels  can be operated at maximum power point since it is a small instrument and can easily fit to my box.Any suggestion from your side so that i can track the maximum power from the panels

Comment: The first 1 is Mppt charge controller.